# Блокировка кнопки отправка коммантариев в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, form, submit, комментарии

Добрый день друзья, я столкнулся с такой трудностью, мне необхдимо делать кнопку отправки комментариев "disable" елси пользователь не авторизован, и с подписью того рода типа после авторизации вам будет дана возможность отправлять комментарии.
Вот мой код:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'comments_submit_hide' );

function comments_submit_hide( $content ) {
    if ( !(is_user_logged_in() )) {
        $comment_button = '<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Отправить">';
        $dis_comment_button = 'input type="button" class="hover_block" value="Отправить" disabled data-title="Текст подсказки"
    <br><h4>Для отправки формы Вам необходимо авторизоваться через соц.сети</h4';
    $content = preg_replace( $comment_button, $dis_comment_button, $content);
    } else {

    }

return $content;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение данной задачки:

```
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'mytheme_remove_defaults');
function mytheme_remove_defaults($defaults) {
 if ( !(is_user_logged_in() )) {
 $defaults['submit_button' ]='<input type="button" class="hover_block" value="Отправить комментарий" disabled><br>
 <h3>Для отправки комментария Вам необходимо авторизоваться через  соц.сети</h3>';} else {}
return $defaults;}
```